# Show that the function $f(t) = \dim\text{Range}(T - tI)$ is not a continuous function.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$, which is at least $1$.

Assume that the number field for $V$ is $\textbf{R}$, the real number field.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$, which has at least one eigenvalue.

- Show that the function

$$f(t) = \dim\text{Range}(T - tI)$$

is not a continuous function.

2. Where is $f$ continuous? Why?

My linear algebra class has not gone over the criteria for proving something is continuous or not and I couldn't find it in the textbook so I was struggling with this problem. I started by taking $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue so $f(\lambda) = \dim\text{Range}(T - \lambda I))$ which I got to be $0$ and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: A few comments: the number $\text{dim Range}(T-tI)$ is always a non-negative integer. Therefore the function will not be continuous at those points where the dimension of the range of $T-tI$ "jumps" from one number to another. 
As you pointed out the eigenvalues are somewhat special for this function because we have "$\lambda \in \mathbb R$ is eigenvalue of $T$" $\Leftrightarrow \text{dim Range}(T-\lambda I) <n$
How can you get to information about $f(t)$ from that fact and where is $f$ continuous (a constant function is continuous...)? Hope these comments help you.

Comment: Continuity is a notion in Calculus, or Analysis, so it seems unlikely to find such criteria in linear algebra textbooks. Use definition of continuity to prove that $f$ is only continuous on intervals where $f$ is constant. Then $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ iff $f$ is constant on $\Bbb R$, which fails because $T$ has eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you guys, @xbh, I think I understand conceptually how to approach this proof now. I'm wondering how I can show that f(t) =/= 0 for some t that is not an eigenvalue to show that it is not constant?

Comment: That's not it. You should show that $f$ is not constantly $n$, since we are dealing with the dimension of a range, not a kernel. And $f$ is not constantly $n$ because for $t$ being an eigenvalue, $\operatorname{Range}(T - tI)$ would be a proper subspace of $V$, hence the dimension is less than $n$.